# With Airfoil, can you have synchronized audio and video in Firefox?

Tags: macos, mac, firefox

When watching video and sending the audio using Airfoil to an Airport Express there is a 2-3 seconds delay in the sound.

In VLC it's possible to change the video/audio sync. Is there a more generic way of doing this on a Mac? So that you can watch any kind of video (Flash, Quicktime etc) in a browser and send the audio to your Airport Express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this not what the Airfoil Video Player seeks to address: delaying the video displayed locally to compensate for the audio delay?

(If there's a video format it doesn't support that you really want, let Rogue Amoeba know!)

Answer (score 2):

Try :[QT Sync](http://www.qtsync.com/qtsync.php)

I guess this might be useful link : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=203332

Comment: Is possible to replace the embedded qt-player with qt sync? And how about other embedded plugins such as flash, java etc?

Comment: Yes ! You can .. http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=206210

Comment: the link explains how to install the standard quicktime player or the quicktime alternative as a plugin not qt sync.